# Django Cant query Oracle

Tags: django, oracle

I have a Django application, and it works fine. So far, the connection to Oracle seems to be ok. The problems is when I try to query data. I use the objects property and it gives me

> "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

error. So far I ven looking the query and I think is the problem. Anyway, I try that same query on oracle and sems to be pk

```
print(CONTRIBUYENTES.objects.using('VIALISDB').all().query)
SELECT "FGESILDOWN.SILD_DET_CONTRIBUYENTES"."DTCO_FOLIOSOLICITUD" FROM "FGESILDOWN.SILD_DET_CONTRIBUYENTES"
```

Does someone knows the problem?